# Query to modify where clause to specify relation

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: users & user_roles

```
users:
id   name
1    John
2    Doe
```

```
user_roles:
user_id role
1       admin
1       finance
1       accounting
2       admin
2       finance
2       admin
```

I want to get the users that have admin & finance roles in the output(with distinct).

So the result will be only user with ID of 2 (Doe)

What is the best SQL solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys I found the solution. so it might help someone with the same problem with me

```
select u.id, u.name
from users u
INNER join user_roles ur on ur.user_id = u.id
group by u.id, u.name
having
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN ur.role IN ('admin', 'finance') THEN ur.role END)) = 2
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN ur.role NOT IN ('admin', 'finance') THEN ur.role END)) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
SELECT name
FROM users
    INNER JOIN user_roles ON user_roles.user_id = users.id
WHERE user_roles.role = 'admin'
    AND user_roles.role = 'finance'
    AND user_roles.user_id IN (
        SELECT user_id
        FROM user_role
        GROUP BY user_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
select * from users 
where exists (select 1 from user_roles where user_id=users.id and role='admin')
and exists (select 1 from user_roles where user_id=users.id and role='finance')
and not exists (select 1 from user_roles where user_id=users.id and role not in ('admin','finance'))
```

Best regards,
Bjarni

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select u.id, u.name
from users u join
     user_roles ur
     on ur.user_id = u.id
group by u.id, u.name
having count(distinct case when u.role in ('admin', 'finance') then u.role end) = 2;
```

Or:

```
select u.id, u.name
from users u join
     user_roles ur
     on ur.user_id = u.id
where u.role in ('admin', 'finance') 
group by u.id, u.name
having count(distinct u.role) = 2;
```

Comment: The u.role should be ur.role, but this will still not work.  It should return those who have finance and admin ONLY, but this returns those who have additional roles.  It will also not return users that have roles duplicated (that may be prevented with constraints on table ofc).

Comment: that's right. it still returning user 1 (john) as well

Comment: @JimmyJS . . . Oh, you want *only* those two roles.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hm that one also returning the user 1 (john) as well

Comment: @JimmyJS . . . Why does the table have duplicates?

Comment: even without duplicates it still returning user 1 (john). you can try that

Comment: @JimmyJS . . . Please set up a db<>fiddle.